# Datatype mismatch when reading recordset in vba access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to do a calculation depanding on several conditions, so I tried to get the output using

> CurrentDb.OpenRecordset

Fist I checked the query if it works by creating query in Ms Access and it worked and returned me the answer I want, so I applied the select statement in my VBA code but it did not work, it give me error (type mismatch) on :

> TOTER = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & _ ..est

Why  it work perfectly without VBA? what I am missing in my code? 
I put it in a function

> GET_TOTER()

and called the function from

> TABLE_x_NEW()

```
  Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public db As DAO.Database

Public Sub SUb_Main()
    Set db = Access.Application.CurrentDb
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
TABLE_x_NEW
End Sub

Private Sub TABLE_x_NEW()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim SDATA As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim TX As DAO.Recordset
    Set TX = db.OpenRecordset("TABLE_x")

    sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_z"
    SDATA.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

    If SDATA.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        Do Until SDATA.EOF
        DoEvents
            TX.AddNew
            TX!P_ID = SDATA!P_ID
            TX!Pdate = SDATA!Pdate
            TX!W_TOTER = GET_TOTER(TX!Pdate, TX!P_ID)
            TX.Update
            SDATA.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub

Private Function GET_TOTER(Pdate As Date, PID As String) As Double

    Dim sql As String
    Dim SDATA As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim COUN As Long
    Dim TOTER As Double  
             sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (NID) FROM TABLE_A WHERE P_ID='" & PID & "' AND PTYPE IN ('HP','TOS')"
             SDATA.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

    If SDATA.RecordCount <> 0 Then

          COUN = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM TABLE_B WHERE APId = '" & SDATA!NID & "' " & _
        "AND MONTH(W_DATE)=" & Month(Pdate) & " AND YEAR(W_DATE)=" & Year(Pdate) & "").Fields(0).Value

        If (0 >= COUN >= 3) Then        
              TOTER = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & _
            "(DAvg(""[W_RATE]"",""TABLE_B"",""[APId] = '" & SDATA!NID & "' AND MONTH([WELL_TEST_DATE])=' & Month(Pdate) & ' AND YEAR([WELL_TEST_DATE])= ' & Year(Pdate) & ' "") " & _
           " -DStDev(""[W_RATE]"", ""TABLE_B"", ""[APId] = '" & SDATA!NID & "' AND MONTH([WELL_TEST_DATE])=' & Month(Pdate) & ' AND YEAR([WELL_TEST_DATE])= ' & Year(Pdate) & ' ""))" & _
           " / DAvg(""[W_RATE]"",""TABLE_B"",""[APId] = '" & SDATA!NID & "' AND MONTH([WELL_TEST_DATE])=' & Month(Pdate) & ' AND YEAR([WELL_TEST_DATE])= ' & Year(Pdate) & ' "") *100 " & _
           " +(20 * (1- COUNT(APId)/3)) + 5 " & _
           " FROM TABLE_B" & _
           " WHERE Month(W_DATE) = ' & Month(Pdate) & '  AND Year(W_DATE)= ' & Year(Pdate) & '  AND APId = '" & SDATA!NID & "' HAVING  COUNT(APId) BETWEEN 0 AND 3")
            GET_TOTER = TOTER     
           ELSE
          GET_TOTER=0        
        End If

             SDATA.Close
        End If   
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `OpenRecordset` is returning a `RecordSet`, not a `Double`.  You just need to change how you retrieve the data, something like the following:

```
Set MyRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & _
Toter = MyRecordSet.Fields(0).Value
```

Comment: I didn't notice that I forget to add '.Fields(0).Value ' to the record set! thank you..